# Iterating in rails view over multiple variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, erb

I'm accessing attributes from several different variables of several different models. I'm trying to find the best way to display these attributes in a table, and I'm getting some unwanted duplication in my view. Here's the relevant part of my table.

```
<% @list_items.each do |l| %>
  <% @i_items.each do |i| %>
    <% @details.each do |d| %>
      <% @vends.each do |v| %>
        <tr>        
          <td><%= d.product %></td>
          <td><%= d.brand %></td>
          <td><%= d.details %></td>
          <td><%= i.price %></td>
          <td><%= v.name %></td>
          <td><%= v.address %></td>
          <td><%= button_to "Delete", {:controller => :list_items, 
                        :action => 'destroy', 
                        :id => l.id}, 
                        :method => :delete %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This currently duplicates the rows I want to view by 4x (presumably because I've got 4 `do` blocks going on and am not properly using them to achieve my goal. Any tips on how to make this work and what I'm `do`-ing wrong (sorry couldn't help myself)? Also open to suggestions about how to do this a bit more cleanly than my silly way of using 4 variables? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be worth adding to your question what your expected output is. Do you want one row per `@list_items` element, per `@i_items` element or per `@details` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I'm getting from this is you have these 4 lists that you want to iterate over at once? If that is the issue, do something like this:

```
<% 0.upto(@list_items.count) do |i| %>
  <tr>        
     <td><%= @details[i].product %></td>
     <td><%= @details[i].brand %></td>
     <td><%= @details[i].details %></td>
     <td><%= @i_items[i].price %></td>
     <td><%= @vends[i].name %></td>
     <td><%= @vends[i].address %></td>
     <td><%= button_to "Delete", {:controller => :list_items, 
                    :action => 'destroy', 
                    :id => @list_items[i].id}, 
                    :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

This is making the assumption that all the arrays are the same length and that order has not been altered. This is not really a safe idea and redesigning your models might be something worth looking into.

Comment: each_with_index probably makes more sense here than upto: `@list_items.each_with_index do |item, index|`

Comment: You're right, probably not a good idea. Your comment about redesigning my models made me realize that I had all the associations in place to be smart about this. I didn't need all of those variables in my controller. I put what I think is a good solution in an answer below. +1 for the suggestion and answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the suggestion of @kristenmills I sort of realized that I had the necessary associations to do this really cleanly with the below code. Someone probably would've pointed this out had I posted all of my associations and given a bit more background.

```
<% @list_items.each do |l| %>
<tr>
        <td><%= l.item.product %></td>
        <td><%= l.item.brand %></td>
        <td><%= l.item.details %></td>
        <td><%= l.inventory_item.price %></td>
        <td><%= l.inventory_item.vendor.name %></td>
        <td><%= l.inventory_item.vendor.address %></td>
        <td><%= button_to "Delete", {:controller => :list_items, 
                        :action => 'destroy', 
                        :id => l.id}, 
                        :method => :delete %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```